# Add <enter> to .exrc shortcut

Tags: vim, vi

I found this cool exrc file to make the F-Keys to things, e.g. `map #2 :set number`, which puts just that in that ex command thingy, and lets me press enter to confirm. However, I made one to close (`map #4 :q`) and I would like it if it automatically added an enter, so it just closes without me having to press enter first. Then I would just hit  and it closes.

How do I add that enter character?

Comment: @ChrisWalton Yes it is, I wanted to make it execute that command automatically, and didn't know how!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to add `<CR>` at the end of your mapping:

```
map <F4> :q<CR>
```

See `:help key-notation`.